# How to download a file from another Sharepoint Domain

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I need to download a file stored in a SharePoint server that is in a different domain from the user.  I've found the code below and it looks exactly like what I need.

```
using (FileInformation ffl = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(_clientCtx, serverFilePath))
{
    using (Stream destFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(completeDestinationPath))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = ffl.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            destFile.Write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that I do not know to how supply the user name & password that will allow access to the SharePoint server so I can download the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code won't work because the SharePoint server object model won't cross boundary of the farm (to be verified actually)

I believe you can handle this scenario using a classic http download, unaware of any sharepoint product:

```
var url = "http://otherserver/documents/mydocument.doc";
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true; // May be replaced by explicit credential
wc.DownloadFile(url, @"c:\somewhere\mydocument.doc");
```